# Solving second order differential equation with bvp4c (not having matching dimensions)

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

Suppose I have the BVP

ny^(n-1)-2*phi*y''=0, where n and phi are given.
y(0)=y(5)=4

In order to use BVP4c, I first convert this into a system of first order differential equations

say y_1=y and y_2=y'

Then we get the system

y'_1 = y2,
y'_2 = (nx^(n-1))/(2*phi)

I now write a matlab function to do this to do this i.e

```
function sol=bvpsolve(n,phi)

function dydx = odefun(x,y)
dydx = [y(2);(n*y(1)^(n-1))/(2*phi)]
end

function res = bcfun(ya,yb)
res = [ ya(1) -1.0; yb(1) -4.0]
end


solinit = bvpinit(linspace(0,5,4),[1 0]);
sol = bvp4c(@odefun,@bcfun,solinit);
end
```

I then call the function in the terminal i.e

```
sol=bvpsolve(2,1);
```

I then get this error

```
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

Error in bvp4c>colloc_RHS (line 600)
Phi(1:nBCs) = Gbc(y(:,Lidx),y(:,Ridx),ExtraArgs{1:nExtraArgs});

Error in bvp4c (line 189)
  [RHS,yp,Fmid,NF] = colloc_RHS(n,x,Y,ode,bc,npar,xyVectorized,mbcidx,nExtraArgs,ExtraArgs);

Error in bvpsolve (line 13)
sol = bvp4c(@odefun,@bcfun,solinit);

Error in hw4 (line 3)
sol=bvpsolve(2,1);
```

This appears to be a match error, i.e I'm not matching dimensions for some reason. I matched the documentation found here https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bvp4c.html

basically just redoing what the first example does. Can someone easily see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
res = [ ya(1) -1.0; yb(1) -4.0]
```

looks like the construction of a 2×2 matrix, where in fact you wanted to return the boundary conditions (You said `y(0)=4` in the problem statement?)

Essentially this is a problem of a CAS thinking too much for itself in interpreting the meaning of white-spaces. Just remove the spaces

```
res = [ ya(1)-1.0; yb(1)-4.0]
```

or make the format more explicit

```
res = [ [ ya(1) - 1.0 ]; [ yb(1) - 4.0 ] ]
```

In the example they made the plus sign stand-alone, which also seems to prevent mis-interpretations,

```
res = [ ya(1) - 1.0; yb(1) - 4.0]
```

Comment: Thank you, I get your point, making the interpretation clear made the difference.